# how to display client testimonials in Wordpress, without a plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, client, testimonials

Does anyone know how to display "client testimonials" in Wordpress, without using a plugin? I'm trying to use minimal plugins on my Wordpress website due to security concerns (a LOT of plugins are insecure and unsupported).

I currently display the "client testimonials" using the "blockquote" feature, but it doesn't look that good, and the amount of testimonials currently on the page makes slow the page down too much. So I need something that could paginate as well.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a page http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages that's your better choice

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how this address the issue at hand.

Comment: with a page you can display content, your client testimonial, without a plugin. If you have problems understanding or with the implementation let me know

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing Content Management, which is what @PedroVentura is referring to, with Content Styling, that's how things are displayed in your site.

Lots of themes create a Testimonials [Custom Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types) and offer a variety of displaying methods.

I just found out this plugin, [Testimonials by Woo Themes](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/testimonials-by-woothemes/), that does exactly that. And their code is top notch as well as the support and documentation.

If you want the "no plugins" way, create your CPT (of the non-hierarchical variety) and use Widgets and theme customizations to display it. So, it can be treated just like blog posts, with pagination, custom categories, individual media galleries, etc.

Sites of interest:

- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/
- http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/
- http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/search.php?q=custom+post+type